# button in a div is hiding behind another div while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button register like in the below image. It's fixed and when the user scrolls page the button does not move. [image]

But now I added a popup on page load. like:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="close" style="color:#FFFFFF;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times; </button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="container content-box">
                <div style="padding-top:20px;" class="col-sm-6">
                    <h3 class="rv1">Fed up with Staff Nurse Entrance Exam?</h3 ><h1 class="rv2">Download <span style="color:#ce3328">Nurses Pulse</span> &amp; Prepare for the exam.</h1>
                    <p class="rv3">NursesPulse is a mobile application for those who are preparing for the staff nurse entrance exam for abroad.
                                                     With NursesPulse you will get the notification of vacancies,apply for the exams and practice for the exams.</p>
                    <a style="background-color:#00b02f;margin-bottom:20px;" class="btn btn-success btn-lg rv4" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluroe.nursespulse"><i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download Android Application</a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <img class="image" src="images/phone.png" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when the page is scrolled, when the button reaches this particular div, it hides behind it and when the div is over, it shows again. 
below is my popup css

```css
.popup
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:40%;
    z-index: 1030;
}
.isAnswerStyle{
    color: #090;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#img-upoloader{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.bg{
   background: url("images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center top fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.content-box {
    display: table;
    padding-top: 100px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.content-box p{
    color: #EEE;
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Should be an issue with `z-index`

Comment: how do i fix this

Comment: Do some research now. Don't depend on spoon feeding.

Comment: agreed. `z-index` is a great help already.

Comment: post you html and css codes.

Comment: @AryanTwanju i ve posted html

Comment: post the css code as well

Comment: @AryanTwanju i have posted it

Comment: your html and css code doesn't seem related to the image you have shown

Comment: the image which i showed is not of the popup. its my home page. the popup appears on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by adding high `z-index` to your button or button container:

```
.button {
   z-index:50;
}
```

`z-index` controls the depth of the element on the page. For example, if two absolutely positioned elements in the same spot on the page have different `z-index`, the one with the higher `z-index` will appear over top.

Just make sure your button has a higher `z-index` than your popup.

Comment: i ve alredy done it like this   .sniper {

    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat what is the z-index of the pop up? Please post relevant css in the question

Comment: i have posted the css now

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat Ok, I see it. Like I said in my answer, the element with the highest z-index will appear on top. Your pop up has a z-index of 1030. Either change it to below 100, or change the button z-index to over 1030